# How to split selenium python code into multiply functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm writing a python program which will test some functions on website. It will log in to this site, check it version and do some tests on it regarding the site version. I want to write few tests for this site but few things will repeat, for example login to the site.

I try to split my code into functions, like hue_login() and use it on every test I need to login to the site. To login to site I use selenium webdriver. So If I split the code into small functions and try to use it in other function where I also use selenium webdriver I end up with two browser windows. One from my hue_login() function where function log me in. And second browser window where it try to put url where I want to go after I log in to the site interface. Of course, because I am not login into the second browser window, site wont show and other tests will fail (tests from this second function).

Example:

```
def hue_version():
    url = global_var.domain + global_var.about
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
    xpath = etree.parse(response, htmlparser).xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/h2/text()')
    string = "".join(xpath)

    pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}).(\d{1,2}).(\d{1,2})')
    return pattern.search(string).group()

hue_ver = hue_version()

print(hue_ver)

if hue_ver == '3.9.0':
    do something
elif hue_version == '3.7.0':
    do something else
else:
    print("Hue version not recognized!")


def hue_login():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(global_var.chromeDriverPath)
    driver.get(global_var.domain + global_var.loginPath)
    input_username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
    input_password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    input_username.send_keys(username)
    input_password.send_keys(password)

    input_password.submit()
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_id('jHueTourModalClose').click()


def file_browser():
    hue_login()
    click_file_browser_link = global_var.domain + global_var.fileBrowserLink
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(global_var.chromeDriverPath)
    driver.get(click_file_browser_link)
```

How can I call hue_login() from file_browser() function that rest of the code from file_browser() will be executed in the same window opened by hue_login()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(global_var.chromeDriverPath)

def hue_login():    
    driver.get(global_var.domain + global_var.loginPath)
    input_username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
    input_password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    input_username.send_keys(username)
    input_password.send_keys(password)

    input_password.submit()
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_id('jHueTourModalClose').click()

def file_browser():
    hue_login()
    click_file_browser_link = global_var.domain + global_var.fileBrowserLink
    driver.get(click_file_browser_link)
```

Comment: When I change last two line from file_browser() to `driver = webdriver.Chrome(global_var.chromeDriverPath).current_url
    driver.get(click_file_browser_link)` I got error `driver.get(click_file_browser_link)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: the easiest way would be to define your driver outside any function, then you can call it from every where.

Comment: Or if you want to declare it in function, then you can either declare it in file_browser() and then path further or leave it like you have right now but return from hue_login(), but that doesn't look nice

Comment: Can you please show the proper code taking my code example, because I'm not sure how to write this and don't get errors? Im pretty new in python and not all understand. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have done that but forgot to remove current_url part from my code and that cause the problems :)